# Saving results from for loop and incrementing the index

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I'm writing a program to compute the resultants of distributed forces.
My method works like this:

```
force =[1,2,3,4,5]
distance =[2,3,4,5,6]
```

The idea is to break any section of a distributed force into 2 triangles whose area can be found using:

```
lowerarea = ((distance[i+1] - distance[i]) *force[i]) * 0.5
upperarea = ((distance[i+1] - distance[i]) *force[i+1]) * 0.5
```

This is my for loop to find the lower areas:

```
for i in range(0,len(force)):
lowerarea= (dist[i+1]-dist[i])*force[i]*0.5
print (f)

i = i+1
```

I obviously get the error that the index is out of bounds since `d[6]` doesn't exist how do i stop the loop once `d[5]` is evaluated?

Also how do i save the output of the loop `f` to a new variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Just change `range(0,len(force))` to `range(0,len(force) - 1)`. Save the results with `result = []` outside the loop and `result.append(lowerarea)` inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a new list?

```
results = []

for (...):
   results.append(f)
```

Your out-of-range error is due to the fact that `len(force) == 6` -- you want `len(force) - 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will accept answer once I am allowed to. Once again thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the index going out of bounds is because you're doing an additional increment with `i = i+1`. Remove that line, because the loop is already doing that increment for you. By having it in there, you're pushing the value of i beyond `len(force) - 1` (which as the other folks already pointed out is the highest index of these arrays).

As to `f`, you're not using or changing it at all during the loop, so why print it or try to store its value? The value isn't going to change anywhere in this code.

Comment: Python `for` loops don't work like that. When control reaches the top of the loop again, `i` will get the next value from the sequence regardless how you have changed it inside the loop

Comment: Huh, didn't know that, thanks for the tip. In that case, this wouldn't affect the outcome of this problem, but it's still something the OP should remove.

Comment: yep, it's confusing/misleading to leave it in there